# Dialog box closing on its own

Tags: php, jquery, html, alert, jquery-ui-dialog

When an alert box is opened it automatically closes the existing opened dialog box. I want to ensure dialog box does not close automatically when errors messages are displayed.I tried using return false but that doesnt work 
Not sure where am I going wrong.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new category">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="9" id="code" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
            <label for="name">Year</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="4" value=""
                   class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

$(function () {     
    var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
        var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
        var year = dlg.find(("#acad_year")),
        code = dlg.find(("#acad_code"));
        type = type || 'Create';
        var config = {
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Create Academic Year": function () {
                    save_data("create");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                dlg.remove();
            }
        };        

        function save_data(strings) {
            var id;
            dlg.dialog("close");
            if (strings == 'edit') {
                id = $(row.children().get(0)).text();
            } else {
                id = "NU=L";
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'acad_year.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    from: strings,
                    acad_year: year.val(),
                    acad_code: code.val()
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response[0] === "REDUNDANT") {
                        alert("Data already exists. ");
                    }else if(response[0] === "EMPTY"){

                       alert("Data can't be left empty "); 
                    } else {
                        sortTable(1);
                        $("#acodes tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td style='display:none;'>" + response[1] + "<td>" + year.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + code.val() + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span id='" + response[1] + "' class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");     
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("ERROR.." + error[0]);
                }
            });

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alerting error you can write error message.
Example:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="Error-msg" style="display:none;"></div>
    ...Some Form ....
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    if(error){
    $("#Error-msg").append("<p>You have an error</p>");
    }

</script>
```

Instead of

```
error: function (error) {
alert("ERROR.." + error[0]);
}
```

You can use

```
error: function (error) {
$("#Error-msg").append("ERROR.." + error[0]);
}
```